# WPF: make mouse enter/leave work on back peer while click works on front

Tags: c#, wpf, routed-events

The code below is a complete example of my conundrum. I need mouse enter/leave events to work on the back peer while still having mouse events work on the front peer. So far I can only get one or the other. I get the background events to work by removing the Background on the front grid (and then my click events don't work). How can I make all events in this work? I don't really want to change the logical/visual structure as my real application is much more complex than this example.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace DemoBadEnterEvent
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main()
        {
            var frontGrid = new Grid
            {
                Background = Brushes.Transparent // remove this for enter/leave to work
            };

            var backGrid = new Grid();
            var backEllipse = new Ellipse
            {
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
                Width = 200,
                Height = 200,
                Fill = Brushes.LightSteelBlue,
                StrokeThickness = 10,
                Stroke = Brushes.Transparent,
                Cursor = Cursors.Arrow
            };

            var window = new Window { Width = 300, Height = 300, Cursor = Cursors.Cross };
            var app = new Application();
            backGrid.Children.Add(backEllipse);
            backGrid.Children.Add(frontGrid);
            window.Content = backGrid;

            backEllipse.MouseEnter += (sender, args) => backEllipse.Fill = Brushes.MediumVioletRed;
            backEllipse.MouseLeave += (sender, args) => backEllipse.Fill = Brushes.LightSteelBlue;
            frontGrid.MouseLeftButtonDown += (sender, args) => backEllipse.Stroke = Brushes.Salmon;
            frontGrid.MouseLeftButtonUp += (sender, args) => backEllipse.Stroke = Brushes.Transparent;

            app.Run(window);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: I tried binding to the IsMouseOver property, but it has nothing on MouseEnter.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the layout, you won't be able to get mouse events on the backEllipse. One thing you can do is catch mouse moves on the frontGrid and do a hit test on the on backEllipse:

```
frontGrid.MouseMove += (sender, args) => backEllipse.Fill = 
    (VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(backEllipse, args.GetPosition(backEllipse)) == null)
    ? Brushes.LightSteelBlue
    : Brushes.MediumVioletRed;
```

Comment: So is the MouseEnter behavior the same as a hit test on every MouseMove? Or is the native MouseEnter somehow more efficient than that?